# EXC_BAD_ACCESS When I click a button inside a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I build a TableView with custom TableViewCell, the first custom cell have a tool bar and some Bar button Item and also a simple button for test.
The problem is : When I click in any bar button item or into simple button I have a EXC_BAD _ACCESS ?

This is my code to build the tableview cells :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"taskCell";

    if(indexPath.row != 0){

        TaskCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {

            NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TaskCell" owner:nil options:nil];

            for (UIView *view in views) {
                if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
                {
                    cell = (TaskCell*)view;
                }
            }
        }
        return cell;
    }
    else{

        if (travelInfoCell == nil) {

            NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TravelInfo" owner:nil options:nil];

            for (UIView *view in views) {
                if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
                {
                    travelInfoCell = (TravelInfo*)view;
                }
            }
        }

        travelInfoCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return travelInfoCell;
    }

}
```

I planed to delegate the action code to the TableViewController, but for the instant I can not even hit the breakpoint in front of the button IBAction.

Code into the TravelInfo.m and is not working and throw to me EXC_BAD _ACCESS :

```
- (IBAction)doAccepted:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"accepted");
    //[delegate travelAccepted];
}
```

Do have any solution ?

Comment: As nob1984 said, you can either retain the view and the release it in the viewDidUnload method or you can allocate the memory space so that the pointer is not released before you want it to be. All EXC_BAD_ACCESS means is that you are accessing a pointer whose object has been terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
travelInfoCell = (TravelInfo*)view;
```

You are not keeping a reference to the view, so there is an implicit limited life expectancy to the view variable.  You'll need to retain to keep a reference.  Do this:

```
travelInfoCell = [(TravelInfo*)view retain];
```

Don't forget to release the cell and nil it out on viewDidUnload

Comment: Hi nob1984, Thank you. I add retain like you did but a I still have the same problem. For your info : I can't set an Outlet from the custom cell nib file inside the cell custom class, it throw me this exception when the tableview call : - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath :  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x6811210> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key btnReject.'

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing what you are trying to say.  TravelInfo is a custom cell that is loaded via a nib of the same name.  The exception you are seeing indicates to me that in that nib you are trying to set an outlet on the "File Owner", but you can see in your code that the owner is "nil".  Set whatever outlet you are trying to set on the table view cell in you nib NOT the File Owner.

Comment: Excuse me for my bad explanation. So what I realized that I can't set outlet in the TravelInfo class until the file owner is nil. But what should I do to assign an owner in my code ?

Comment: TravelInfo doesn't need an owner.  In the TravelInfo xib just set the outlets to the actual UITableView cell and get rid of all outlets set on the File Owner.